# Как отследить какие блоки памяти задействованы при UPDATE в Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, windows-7

Windows 7 64-bit, Postgresql 11.

Есть база в которой выполняются несколько операций UPDATE, насколько я помню, то UPDATE сначала стирает строку, а потом пишет заново в конец таблицы, так вот возникла задача доказать это и отследить какие блоки памяти задействованы при этих операциях в файловой системе, насколько я узнал это можно сделать с помощью программы Process Monitor, но я так и не разобрался каким образом, если это реально можно сделать, то подскажите как?

Если же нет, то каким еще образом я могу отследить какие блоки памяти задействованы при операциях UPDATE внутри моей базы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UPDATE сначала стирает строку, а потом пишет заново в конец таблицы

Не совсем корректны оба утверждения.

PostgreSQL - `MVCC` база, `Multi-Version Concurrency Control`. В таблице одновременно могут содержаться множество разных версий одной строки, и разные транзакции могут видеть разные версии одной строки.

Поэтому корректнее сказать, что операция `update` помечает старую версию строки как видимую только до текущей транзакции. Это именно так и записано в [заголовке строки](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/storage-page-layout.html), где есть ID транзакции в которой эта строка появилась и в которой строка была удалена - xmin и xmax соответственно. Плюс поля cmin и cmax схожего смысла, но для счётчика команд внутри транзакции - чтобы верно интерпретировать ситуацию с множественным обновлением строки в одной транзакции. И сверху разные оптимизации в виде visibility map, флагов видимости страницы, но базово - xmin и xmax.

Куда новая версия строки будет записана - зависит от наличия свободного места. Новая версия строки вполне может быть записана на эту же страницу данных (к тому же в некоторых случаях может быть пропущено обновление индексов - `HOT-update`). Или в любое место таблицы, где есть достаточно свободного места. В конец таблицы - только в худшем случае, когда больше писать было некуда.

Со стороны операционной системы отслеживать модификации конкретных блоков будет сильно затруднительно, т.к. изменения в файлах таблиц существуют отдельно в разделяемой памяти postgresql - в `shared_buffers`. И только в какой-то момент в будущем будут отправлены на запись на диск: при нехватке `shared_buffers`, процессом `bgwriter` либо при наступлении `checkpoint`. Целостность записанных данных при нештатном выключении гарантирует запись write-ahead log - WAL, а не файлы таблиц. По этому журналу после нештатной перезагрузки будут восстановлены все изменения данных.

В исходном коде показать однако не проще. Обновление одной строки таблицы весьма большая и сложная штука, выполняется в функции [`heap_update`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/access/heap/heapam.c#L3486) файла `src/backend/access/heap/heapam.c` для актуальных версий СУБД. И в этой самой функции весьма сильно дальше от её начала начала [можно найти](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/access/heap/heapam.c#L4284):

```
RelationPutHeapTuple(relation, newbuf, heaptup, false); /* insert new tuple */
```

То есть запись новой строки, а после - проставление xmax/cmax старой версии строки `oldtup`, указание этой страницы грязной (отметка, что когда-нибудь потом её необходимо будет записать на диск) и много другой необходимой механики.

Comment: Изучаю Postgres недолго, спасибо за разьяснение. Только еще интересна одна вещь, что происходит при запуске Postgres, база получается считывается с диска в shared_buffers? Или открывается в режиме только записи\дозаписи?

Comment: Это отдельный пост писать надо, и боюсь подробно описать что происходит при старте не потяну я =) Это при том, что грядущие в pg12 изменения режимов recovery/standby - мой же патч. Если кратко и не подробно, то при старте база читает control файл, на его основе вычитывает и применяет все WAL если видит что выключение было нештатное, затем начинает принимать соединения. Все операции с данными происходят только в shared_buffers, процессы базы читают из файлов нужные себе кусочки 8кб данных в буфер, при нехватке объёма буфера - выкидывают оттуда редко используемые страницы.

Comment: Возникает тогда ещё такой вопрос, а как будет происходить запись на диск, при отключенном WAL, одна из задач стоит, чтобы добиться максимальной частоты записи на диск. И вопрос совсем не по теме, если не затруднит, интересен тоже был бы ответ, весь интернет перерыл не нашел точной информации, есть ли в Postgres какая-либо адаптация под память NAND Flash, либо движки может какие под это дело?

Comment: Вы не можете отключить запись WAL. Есть unlogged таблицы - запись в них через wal не проходит, при старте после нештатного выключения таблица будет принудительно очищена. В остальном ведёт себя как обычная таблица, запись только внутри shared_buffers, оттуда пишется на диск. По поводу NAND - postgresql пишет WAL строго последовательно, данные читает и пишет фиксированными блоками по 8кб. Остальное взаимодействие с железом на откуп операционной системе.

Comment: Да про Unlogged table видел, но тогда если правильно я понимаю, что при невысокой нагрузке например <10 записей в секунду, можно добиться скорости записи на диск, что при нештатном выключении записи теряться не будут?

Comment: После нештатного выключения все unlogged таблицы очищаются. Независимо от всего. Условие вида если стартуем нештатно - то очистить unlogged таблицы. Писать WAL не проблема. Это последовательная запись, любимый паттерн для HDD и реально можно держать определённую нагрузку с WAL на механике. Для SSD последовательная запись тоже идёт хорошо, и именно эти цифры любит писать маркетинг. А вот много random io при записи самих таблиц - вот тут как раз внятные накопители и нужны. На hdd жизни не будет, ssd нужны приличные.